# Не получается подключить библиотеку: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю все, как [описано в этом гайде](https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-firstprograms.html), но ничего не получается.

Вот код

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidgets, QDesktopWidget, QApplication
```

Вот ошибка

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 2, in  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidgets, QDesktopWidget, QApplication
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'

Использую Python 3.6 32-bit

Решил из интереса посмотреть на питона, а он ругается и не хочет ничего показывать.

Comment: Вопрос должен иметь смысл даже если ссылка умрёт в вашем вопросе. Поэтому явно шаги, как вы пытались установить pyqt5, приведите.

Comment: Скачал PyQt5 с оф. сайта, переименовал папку в "PyQt5" и закинул её в Lib. Пробовал и через Pip, устанавливал и в PyCharm. Пробовал разные версии питона. 3.4, 3.5, 3.6. Ничто не помогло

Comment: вся информация необходимая для ответа должна быть в самом вопросе. Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии к собственному вопросу, отредактируйте сам вопрос вместо этого (см. кнопка [edit] под вопросом). "Ничто не помогло" -- не информативно (вместо этого лучше писать: сделал "то-то", ожидал "это", а получил "вот это" по шагам).

Comment: Редактируй вопрос сам. У меня нет желания делать этого. Все равно на вопрос нет ответов и не будет. Проблема гуглится за 5 секунд, ответа нет нигде.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно. Поставил PyCharm и python 3.6.2 как интерпретатор проекта, плюс установил через pip3 библиотеку PyQt5. Сделал [как в гайде сказано](https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-firstprograms.html) и та же ошибка. Если запускать из терминала файл с кодом вне PyCharm, то все работает, так как в операционной системе используется python 3.5.2. Если запускать из PyCharm, то не работает.
У меня Ubuntu 16.04, а это значит, что для воспроизведения ошибки ОС не важна.

Изменил в настройках проекта интерпретатор на версию python 3.5.2 и все заработало. Присмотрелся и увидел, что в основной используемой системой версии python 3.5.2 есть библиотека PyQt5, а при смене интерпретатора проекта на python 3.6.2 ее нет.

Лечится так:
File - Settings - Project:{name_my_project} - Project Interpreter - устанавливаем нужную нам версию интерпретатора(python 3.6.2 например) - Install(плюсик сбоку) - Available Packages - набираем в поиске PyQt5 - нажимаем Install Package

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5` команда по ссылке ставит PyQt5 на системный питон (Python 3.5 на вашей Ubuntu). `pip3` не ясно к какому питону относится у вас. Ожидаемо, если вы настроили PyCharm использовать  Python 3.6, то в PyCharm вы и не увидите PyQt5 -- если хотите использовать Python 3.6 ставьте для него библиотеки, если хотите использовать Python 3.5, то отдельно библиотеки ставить следует. Вы ожидали, что поставив для Python 3.5, у вас автоматически PyQt5 на Питоне 3.6 заработает?

Comment: В данном случае один и тот же дистрибутив (`PyQt5-5.9-5.9.1-cp35.cp36.cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` на Linux) можно использовать для установки на разные версии с помощью одной и той же команды `pip install PyQt5` внутри соответствующего virtualenv. Для каждого Питона отдельно программу установки запускайте.

Comment: Ваши комментарии верны, однако я лишь воспроизвел проблему и нашел из нее выход. Использование virtualenv значительно правильней и удобней. Совершенно с вами согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что библиотека называется `PyQt5.QtWidgets`

Comment: Все равно from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidgets, QDesktopWidget, QApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'. Это я просто из интереса изменил текст. Нужно поправить вопрос.

Comment: Ммм. python3-pyqt5 и pyqt5-dev-tools стоят?

Comment: Я скачал PyQt5_gpl-5.9.zip [с этой страницы](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), переименовал папку в PyQt5 и копировал её в папку Lib питона

Comment: @TryCatch, а вы знаете, что Вы скачали source-файлы, а не бинарники? Следующий абзац это то, что нужно Вам

Comment: Если вы [об этом](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5#downloads), то сейчас скачал  [PyQt5-5.9-5.9.1-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win32.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/14/60/cc8aacfc5c7fd1eb54aa91982d189b052100b2884ba7bc77b3515879a17d/PyQt5-5.9-5.9.1-cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win32.whl#md5=640473b50f6387c08fd84349793460ba), но мне такой формат не знаком и я даже не представляю куда его засовывать

Comment: @TryCatch, нет. Я о том, что хорошо бы сделать вот так: sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 pyqt5-dev-tools

Comment: У меня винда. Ыаы (Комментарий должен быть длиннее 15 символов)

Comment: @TryCatch, тем не менее, PyQt все равно можно поставить через pip. Как-то так: pip3 install PyQt5

Comment: Ок, установил командой python -m pip install -U PyQt5. Во первых в Lib не появилось папки PyQt5, во вторых, разумеется, это все ещё не работает

Comment: @TryCatch, Вы точно установили для Python 3?

Comment: Я не могу этого знать. Как я уже сказал, команда была такой: python -m pip install -U PyQt5. Разве он не достаточно умный для того, что бы самому разобраться какой пакет ему стоит выбрать?

Answer (score -1):

Используйте Pycharm и оттуда качайте библиотеки\модули.
Если же вы уверены, что сделали всё правильно то попробуйте использовать конструкцию from <Имя библиотеки\модуля> import *.

Comment: Просто PyQt5 подключается без проблем. Но не подключается то, что должно